# Does continuity on $S$ implies continuity on $\partial S$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, continuity, riemann-integration

In the book of *Analysis on Manifolds* by Munkres, at page 110, it is given that

[image]

However, the function $f$ is continuous on $S$, and does not have be continuous on the boundary of $S$, so how can he argue as

"**Continuity of $f_S$ at $x_0$ implies ...**" ?

I mean we are already trying to show that $f_S$ is continuos at $x_0$, so I'm really confused how can he base his argument to the statement that he is trying to show.

**Edit:**

$f_X (x)= f(x)$ for $x \in X$, and $f_X(x) = 0$ for $x \not = X$.

Comment: I think the error is in taking $x_0 \in \partial S$, where it really wants $x_0 \in \partial S \cap S$. Not every continuous function on a bounded set can be extended to a continuous function on the closure (classic example, $x \mapsto x^{-1}$ over $(0, 1]$). You need uniform continuity for that.

Comment: @TheoBendit Here $f$ is given as bounded.

Comment: The proof mentions $f_A$ and $f_S$. What are they?

Comment: $f(x)=\sin (1/x)$ on $(0,1]$ is continuous and bounded, but not uniformly continuous, and it cannot be extended to a continuous function over $[0,1]$ since $\not \exists \lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown See my edit.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown So every bounded function can be extended to a continuous function over their closure ?

Comment: You are not trying to prove $f_S$ is continuous at $x_0$. You are trying to prove that **if** $f_S$ is continuous at $x_0$ **then** $f_A$ is continuous at $x_0$.

Comment: @onurcanbektas No, see Lorenzo Q.'s comment.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown You are right. I was actually trying to prove another theorem, and tried imitate this theorem, but did not read the statement of the theorem thoroughly, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Continuity on $S$ does not imply continuity on $\partial S$. Indeed, on $\mathbb{R}$, consider $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ on $B_{\frac{1}{2}}{(\frac{1}{2})}$ = (0, 1) := $S$. Then $f$ is continuous on $S$, but discontinuous on $\partial S$.

Edit: I didn’t notice that it stated $f$ is bounded. But as noted by @user571438, take $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$ on (0,1)

Comment: The question required $ f $ to be bounded on $ S $. However, simply taking $ \sin(\frac{1}{x}) $ on the same set will suffice.

Comment: Ops, yes you’re right. I didn’t notice. I’ll edit my answer. Thanks!